# Does Webpack perform Tree Shaking when one uses Lazy in React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

React 16.6 introduced `Lazy` which enables code-splitting with suspense... I remember that Webpack can't tree-shake non-directed-import files such as async import, but what about this:

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
const OtherComponent = lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <OtherComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

*Example taken from [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html)*

Is Tree-shaking performed in `OtherComponent`?

Comment: Did some searching, maybe this will shed some light on it: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/841258118810075138?lang=en

Comment: @KenoClayton: Oh dang! That's something interesting

Comment: I wanted to add that Webpack does perform tree shaking, but you need to be careful if you do barrelling (or exports to the top). As of now (Haven't tested Webpack 5 as I'm using CRA), Webpack will not perform tree shaking properly and it will include many assets that weren't supposed to be part of the route (I think this lands more in bundle splitting, though).